# No matching distribution found for tensorflow_cpu==2.3.1 while building Docker Image

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, docker-compose

I am trying to build a docker image, but while insstalling the tensorflow, it shows the following error:

> #9 2.293 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow_cpu==2.3.1 (from versions: none)
> #9 2.293 ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow_cpu==2.3.1

My Dockerfile contains

```
FROM python:3.8.8-alpine
WORKDIR /Cropwayy-Project
ADD . /Cropwayy-Project
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","app.py"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem might be originated by some missing library in the alpine image or architecture incompatibility. Try to change the image from `alpine` to `slim`. I tested with slim, and it worked.

```
FROM python:3.8.8-slim
```

Comment: Have you tried to build without cache? `docker build . --no-cache` , or `docker-compose build --no-cache`, if using docker-compose

Comment: yes I have tried the same, even I am not able to install the wheel file as it says "ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.3.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."